# Can you rewrite the root?

Tags: apache, htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Not sure how to word this one but will explain most I can.

I am trying to make the following happen.

1. Re-write this `http://example.com`
2. To this `http://example.com/home/`

Is it possible ?

**update**

Simone Carletti - the method you posted did not work, have you had this work ? Also would it visually change in the browser URL bar to say /home/

John Conde ♦ - this did not work either I was getting a warning from Firefox saying it would never complete so it did not load the page.

Comment: @danlefree He tagged the question as htaccess, thus we can assume he's using Apache.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to redirect A to B, simply place the following directive in your `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect / http://example.com/home/
```

If you want to rewrite / as /name

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /home/ [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert at this so this may be wrong. If so, let me know so I can either correct it or delete it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /home/[L,R=301]
```

**edit**

This [stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/990392/250259) seems to ask the same question. Check it out and see if you find a solution there. If so, let us know so we can post it here for future reference.

Comment: This did not seem to work, but thanks.